# Rails associate by 2 keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations

I have 2 models: notification, mail. In notifications In Notification I have column, object_id and notification_type. In object_id write id from mail, in notification_type - "mail". In future i want add to notification other model name, and associate with its, so I'm need association by id and type model. Now i have association:

```
class Mail < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :notification, -> {where(notification_type: "mail") }, class_name: "Notification", foreign_key: "object_id"
end
```

Its work, but i dont now how do associate in Notification, where will be taken notification type. I try

```
class Notification < ApplicationRecord
   belongs_to :mail, class_name: "Mail", foreign_key: "object_id"
end
```

In this case notification_type not taken into associate.

```
class Notification < ApplicationRecord
   belongs_to :mail, -> {where(notification_type: "mail") }, class_name: "Mail", foreign_key: "object_id"
end
```

I get error

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column mails.notification_type does not exist)
LINE 1: ...ils" WHERE "mails"."id" = $1 AND "mail...
                                                             ^
: SELECT  "mails".* FROM "mails" WHERE "mails"."id" = $1 AND "mails"."notification_type" = $2 LIMIT $3
```

How I'm can take associate in Notifidation model?

Comment: It feels to me like you are building something that already exists in Rails. Is it possible that you want to have a [polymorphic association](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations)?

Comment: Thanks. Now there using polymorphic association)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you want to have composite primary keys? If so you can do like that https://github.com/composite-primary-keys/composite_primary_keys

```
class Membership < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.primary_keys = :user_id, :group_id
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :group
  has_many :statuses, :class_name => 'MembershipStatus', :foreign_key => [:user_id, :group_id]
end
```

A model associated with a composite key model is defined like this:

```
class MembershipStatus < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :membership, :foreign_key => [:user_id, :group_id]
end
```